# Applying an if else function to two string columns in python / pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe I have:

```
Name    Sex    Height
Jackie   F       Small
John     M       Tall
```

I have made the following function to apply to create a new column based off combinations:

```
def genderfunc(x,y):
    if x =='Tall' & y=='M':
        return 'T Male'
    elif x =='Medium' & y=='M':
        return 'Male'
    elif x =='Small' & y=='M':
        return 'Male'
    elif x =='Tall' & y=='F':
        return 'T Female'
    elif x =='Medium' & y=='F':
        return 'Female'
    elif x =='Small' & y=='F':
        return 'Female'
    else:
        return y
```

My line of code to apply this function:

```
df['GenderDetails'] = df.apply(genderfunc(df['Height'],df['Sex']))
```

and i get the following:

> TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and
> scalar of type [bool]

Any ideas on what im doing wrong here? this is my first go at using a function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need lambda function with `axis=1` and because scalar processing use `and`:

```
def genderfunc(x,y):
    if x =='Tall' and y=='M':
        return 'T Male'
    elif x =='Medium' and y=='M':
        return 'Male'
    elif x =='Small' and y=='M':
        return 'Male'
    elif x =='Tall' and y=='F':
        return 'T Female'
    elif x =='Medium' and y=='F':
        return 'Female'
    elif x =='Small' and y=='F':
        return 'Female'
    else:
        return y

df['GenderDetails'] = df.apply(lambda x: genderfunc(x['Height'],x['Sex']), axis=1)
print (df)
     Name Sex Height GenderDetails
0  Jackie   F  Small        Female
1    John   M   Tall        T Male
```

Non loop solution  is possible with helper DataFrame and left join:

```
#set values like need
L = [('Tall','M','T Male'), ('Small','F','Female')]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Height','Sex','GenderDetails'])


df = df.merge(df1, how='left')
print (df)
     Name Sex Height GenderDetails
0  Jackie   F  Small        Female
1    John   M   Tall        T Male
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is another approach, using `map`.

```
map_ = {"TallM": "T Male", "SmallF": "Female"}

df['GenderDetails'] = (df['Height'] + df['Sex']).str.strip().map(map_)
```

---

```
     Name Sex Height GenderDetails
0  Jackie   F  Small        Female
1    John   M   Tall        T Male
```

Answer (score 5):

or you can use np.select, **if performance is a concern**-

```
condlist = [(df['Height'] == 'Tall') & (df['Sex'] == 'M'),
            (df['Height'] == 'Medium') & (df['Sex'] == 'M'),
            (df['Height'] == 'Small') & (df['Sex'] == 'M'),
            (df['Height'] == 'Tall') & (df['Sex'] == 'F'),
            (df['Height'] == 'Medium') & (df['Sex'] == 'F'),
            (df['Height'] == 'Small') & (df['Sex'] == 'F')]
choiselist = [
    'T Male',
    'Male',
    'Male',
    'T Female',
    'Female',
    'Female'
]

df['GenderDetails'] = np.select(condlist, choiselist, df['Sex'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `&` with `and`.

Comment: @pythonic833 I completely disagree with you. The EXACT recommendation was followed by the selected answer. The only difference is that the selected answer had the corrected code. Nevertheless, the answer here is correct.